# How to copy first four characters of every line to the end of that same line?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, replace, repeated-commands

Given a series of lines that look similar to this:

```
2001 "Some Kind of Title," Author's Name, Publication Name, 1 Mar.
2002 "Some Kind of Title," Author's Name, Publication Name, 12 Oct.
2003 "Some Kind of Title," Author's Name, Publication Name, 8 Apr.
2004 "Some Kind of Title," Author's Name, Publication Name, 3 Jun.
```

Is there a way that I could grab those first four characters (the year), and copy them to the end of the line, so that it looks like this:

```
2001 "Some Kind of Title," Author's Name, Publication Name, 1 Mar. 2001
2002 "Some Kind of Title," Author's Name, Publication Name, 12 Oct. 2002
2003 "Some Kind of Title," Author's Name, Publication Name, 8 Apr. 2003
2004 "Some Kind of Title," Author's Name, Publication Name, 3 Jun. 2004
```

Comment: Sure there is: `:%g/^\d\{4}\d\@!/s/^\(\d\{4}\).*\zs/ \1/`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
:% s/\v^(\d{4})(.*)$/\1\2 \1/
```

is one way to do it

- `\v` magic option, to avoid having to escape grouping `()`
- `^` start of line
- `\d{4}` match exactly four digits
- `.*` rest of line
- `\1` `\2` has the matched pattern within `()`

edit: @Jair Lopez mentions in comments, the regular expression can be further improved:

```
:% s/\v^(\d{4}).*/& \1/
```

or the equivalent

```
:% s/\v^(\d{4}).*/\0 \1/
```

- `&` and `\0` contains the whole matched pattern

For further reading, [vimregex](http://vimregex.com/#backreferences) and [regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: `:%s/\v^(\d{4}).*/& \1/` would be a shorter command.

Answer (score 11):

And a solution with a macro:

```
qqyiwA <Esc>pj0q
```

Which means:

```
qq   Record the macro in the register q
yiw  Yank the text described by the text object iw (inner word): The date
A <Esc>   Append a white space to the end of the line and go back to insert mode
p    Paste the date
j0   Place your cursor on the first column of the next line (to be able to repeat the macro)
q    Stop recording
```

You can then replay the macro as many time as you have line with `3@a`.

**Edit** As @evilsoup mentioned it in the comments, a more effective way to execute the macro on all the lines of the buffer is to use:

```
:%normal @q
```

You can of course replace `%` by a [range](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:range) describing the lines to modify.

Comment: You can also execute it on every line with `:%normal @q`

Comment: @evilsoup: Thanks for mentioning that, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the way that I would do it:

```
:%norm y4lA <C-o>p
```

Explanation:

```
:%norm                     "Apply the following keystrokes to every line:
       y4l                 "Yank 4 letters. You could also do 'yiw'
          A                "Add a space to the end
            <C-o>          "Do a single normal command
                 p         "Paste
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to standard UNIX commands, you could use `AWK`:

```
:%!awk '{print $0" "$1}'
```

Comment: Not really vi/vim, then, or the first four characters.

Comment: Considering `:help filter` is a built-in Vim feature and considering how well that feature allows Vim to fit in the UNIX paradigm I would say it's very vi/vim, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the existing mechanisms to do this are better, but it is also possible to do this using **visual block mode**.

Copy the dates:

```
gg          # Go to the top of the file
<ctrl>y     # Enter visual block mode
G           # Go to the bottom of the file
w           # Select the first word
"jy         # Copy in to the j register
```

Pad the end of first line:

```
gg      # Top of file
A       # Append the line
        # Some spaces
<ESC>   # Return to command mode
```

Paste:

```
gg 
# Move right to the length of the longest line
"jp   # Paste the block
```

Comment: Note that you can just do `4l` instead of `llll`

Comment: @EvergreenTree - Updated.

Answer (score 0):

From a unix command line (or windows if you have unix command line tools installed)

```
sed -e "s/\(....\)\(.*\)/\1\2 \1" < inputFile > outputFile
```